# lookup columns are displaying an "ID;#" how to remove them using jquery

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, spservices, jquery-ui

I am using spservices to fetch the lookup value . I have used the below code in All items .aspx and is working fine. However the lookup value is showing like this

**49#;santosh@gmail.com;#19;#afre@gmails.com;#69;#anat@hotmail.com**
I want to remove the id and # and the output should be like this

**santosh@gmail.com;afre@gmails.com;anat@hotmail.com**
below is my code

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" ></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $('#document').ready(function () {

var itemID = "";
var title = "";

  var t = $("table.ms-listviewtable tbody tr.ms-itmhover");

    $(t).each(function() {
     // alert('hi');

       title=$(this).parent().parent().attr('summary');
       console.log(title);
       var iids = $(this).attr('iid').split(',');
       itemID = iids[1]; 
      console.log(itemID);

      $().SPServices({
           operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: title,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='CopyDistributionList' /><FieldRef Name='UsersList' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>"+itemID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
              $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var CSTitle = $(this).attr("ows_CopyDistributionList").replace(/,/g, ';');

        //var lookuptexts= $(this).attr("ows_UsersList");
       var lookuptext= $(this).attr("ows_UsersList").substring(4);
       console.log(lookuptext);
        //console.log(lookuptexts);
      // var updatelist= CSTitle.text().replace(/,/g, ';');
        //alert(CSTitle);

       // UpdateListItem(itemID,title,CSTitle);

              });
           }
        });   
  });

 });

function UpdateListItem(itemid,ListTitle,title)
{
$().SPServices({
operation:"UpdateListItems",
async: false,
batchCmd: "Update",
listName: ListTitle,
ID: itemid,
valuepairs:[["CopyDistributionList",title]],
completefunc:function(xData, Status)
{
//alert("Item Updated");
}
});
}

  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to break out the string explicitly:

```
var emails = $(this).attr("ows_UsersList").split(";#").filter(function(e){ return !parseInt(e)})
var emailsjoined = emails.join(";");
```

`emailsjoined` is the semicolon delimited string of email addresses.

Comment: Awsome you made by day so easier thanks a lot for your help Tons of beer to u man :-)

Comment: glad to have helped! cheers!